# Issue when installing rails apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, apartment-gem

I am getting an error when I am trying to

```
bundle exec rails generate apartment:install
```

Getting this error,

> build': undefined method new' for "Apartment::Reloader":String
>   (NoMethodError)

Looks this is a middleware issue. Any solution.

Comment: Which rails version are you using, which version of the gem?

Comment: I am using rails 6.0.2

Comment: You already got a response on the list of issues in the `apartment` repository. The current gem version is not compatible with rails 6. Unfortunately I have no further knowledge to help you.

Comment: yes it works well with version that is < 6.

Answer (score 6):

In order to use Rails 6 you have to use the development branch on github:

```
gem "apartment", git: 'git@github.com:influitive/apartment.git', branch: "development"
```

Comment: I get this error on "bundle install":

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Solved it using: gem "apartment", github: "influitive/apartment", branch: "development"